# Problem Optimizing Docker Container Start With SqlServer on MacBook OSX

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm a Docker newbie and have managed to create simple steps to create, start and load an image running sqlserver with a database backup.  For me, it's three steps now.

```
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
docker run --name SQL19c -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=xxxx" -v /Users/useraccount/sql:/sql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
docker exec -it SQL19c /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'xxxx' -Q 'RESTORE DATABASE svcodecamp FROM DISK = "/sql/sv-small-2019.bak" WITH MOVE "361684_codecamp08_dat" TO "/var/opt/mssql/ata/codecamp08_dat.mdf", MOVE "361684_codecamp08_log" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/codecamp08_log.mdf"'
```

This is on my macbook running OSX which I reboot frequently so I need to do this everytime I need to use SqlServer.

Questions with this:

1)  Each time I do this, I have to increment the SQL19c to Sql19d (or next letter of alphabet) because I get error saying name in use. How to re-use same name?

2) If I rm the container, it needs to repull the full image (1gig). I need to just start it and reload the data, not pull the full image

3) Is there a more optimum way to start SqlServer and load the data without using too much of my battery every time I reboot my computer or restart docker?

(notice my backup file is on a docker share so I don't need to recopy that in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is because you already have a **container** with this name. Try to execute the command:

```sh
docker container list -a
```

2. If you repull the image I think you remove the **image** NOT the **container** for remove the **container** you must run

```sh
docker container rm SQL19x
```

3. The way is to restart the **container**, drop database and then restore the database

Run **ONCE**: This create a SQL19x **container**

```sh
docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
docker run --name SQL19x -p 1433:1433 -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=xxxx" -v /Users/useraccount/sql:/sql -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

Now each time you restart the machine you must run the command below to start the container and restart the database.

```sh
docker container start SQL19x
docker exec -it SQL19x /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'xxxx' -Q 'DROP DATABASE svcodecamp'
docker exec -it SQL19x /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'xxxx' -Q 'RESTORE DATABASE svcodecamp FROM DISK = "/sql/sv-small-2019.bak" WITH MOVE "361684_codecamp08_dat" TO "/var/opt/mssql/ata/codecamp08_dat.mdf", MOVE "361684_codecamp08_log" TO "/var/opt/mssql/data/codecamp08_log.mdf"'
```

If you want to have a clean shutdown before to poweroff your machine execute

```sh
docker container stop SQL19x
```

Comment: thanks. I think the piece I was missing was the `docker container stop` and start.  works perfect.  Is there a better way to do this that might involve less importing of data? I'd be surprised if I figured out an optimal way to do this on my own, not being a sqlserver or docker wizard.

Comment: If the backup of the db is always the same you can create your own sql server image. Search the web for **Dockerfile**

Comment: I've used docker files and modified some. I can't find any examples of docker files executing sql commands. If you have a pointer to one, that would be helpful.  Also, just to confirm my understanding, when I do docker run ... that parameters I give it are "remembered" so later when I do a docker start, those same command line paramters I originally typed in get executed?

Comment: 1. The parameters are "remembered". 2. [Here](https://www.abhith.net/blog/create-sql-server-database-from-a-script-in-docker-compose/) and [Here](https://cardano.github.io/blog/2017/11/15/mssql-docker-container) you can find examples for execute sql scripts on startup.